# Retrieve new value typed from input type text with ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, webforms

I'm having trouble to retreive a input element of text type when this was previously set some C# code, for example:

The HTML element in **foo.aspx** is defined as:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" runat="server" />
```

From behind code, **foo.aspx.cs**, there's something like this:

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
    bool has_something = ...;
    if(has_something)
        name.Value = "X";
 }
```

when `has_something` is true, now matter if user enter value of Y in the input, when I do something like that (code from **foo.aspx.cs** too):

```
  protected void go_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!IsValid)
                return;

            string Name = name.Value;
            Debug.WriteLine(string.Format("name = {0}", Name)); //X
       }
```

Instead of get current value on input id = name, say, I've typed `Y`, I get old value, as set at `Page_Load()` time.

What am I missing out? should I use Javascript to set the values?
How do I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have edited my original response to correct the answer.

Your code in the Page_Load function is being executed when the page performs a postback upon button click.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            bool has_something = ...;
            if (has_something)
                name.Value = "X";
        }
    }
```

Comment: I think you're confusing, it's a `System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlInputText` not `System.Windows.Forms.TextBox`. There's no a `Text` property...

Comment: exactly. I just found out my mistake too :) I'm very tired